# How to give a label for the max records only

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a data as like below,[image]

People who joined in my company will assign with a system or laptop, the assignment will happen before joining also

I need to add one more column "Updated_flag", 
which have a flag value "Y" for the people whose joining_date_time>system_assign_time and this "Y" for the max value of the system_assign_time.

For the people whose joining_date_time

[image]

for empid 101--> max (system_assign_time) is "2019-03-21 13:21:05 UTC" so the updated flag is "Y" for that record.

for empid 102--> max(system_assign_time) is "2018-0722 14:31:14 UTC" so the updated_flag is "Y" for that record

for 103 there is no change because joining_date_time is less than system_assign_time.

Please help me on this..!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

use scalar subquery with `CASE WHEN Expression`

```
select *,
case when system_assign_time=(select max(system_assign_time) 
      from tablename b where a.empid=b.empid ) then 'Y' else 'N' end as updated_flag
from tablename a
```

Comment: Where joining_date_time>system_assign_time, for those records only in need to change the flag status for other records it should be the old status

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use **over()** function here...

```
SELECT *, 
    CASE WHEN joining_date_time>system_assign_time THEN
        RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY emp_id ORDER BY system_assign_time DESC) 
    ELSE 2 
    END =1 AS flag 
FROM tablename
```

NB: Used boolean instead of 'y' and 'n' because it's more appropriate

Answer (score 0):

You could use  a join on max time group by  empid

```
select a.empid, a.joining_date_time, a.system_assign_time, a.flag
  , case when b.max_time = a.System_assign_time THEN 'Y' ELSE a.flag END update_flag
from  my_table a 
inner join  (
  select  empid, max(System_assign_time)  max_time
  from my_table 
  group by empid  
  ) on a.empid = b.empid
```

Comment: Where joining_date_time>system_assign_time, for those records only in need to change the flag status for other records it should be the old status

Comment: @kalyan4uonly  answer  updated ..  with old flag for others value